# Do I have to do something special to have TestFlight builds use my Notification Extension target? It's ignored

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios10, usernotifications

I added one of the new [iOS 10 Notification Service Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) to my app to present a thumbnail into the push notification received from the server. (Which includes the mutable content flag)

It works perfectly in the development/sandbox environment on my test device. But when I uploaded it to my testers on TestFlight, it's seemingly completely ignored. The thumbnail is never displayed, and I even prepend a little bit of text to the body of the notification as well, and that too is not shown.

Is there something special I have to do to include that in the TestFlight build? The extension itself is a separate target within the project, obviously, and this is the first one in the app, so do I have to explicitly say "include this"?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and let me know if it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you haven't worked with app extensions before. To distribute an App Extension along with an app through AppStore or TestFlight, you need to do the following.

1. Create a separate ID for your App Extension
2. Create a separate App Store Distribution provisioning profile and assign it the App Extension's target

You can try building it and distributing it through TestFlight now. Feel free to comment if it doesn't work

Comment: Where do I create the separate ID? Is this an Xcode or an iTunes Connect thing?

Comment: Yes, it is. I believe that you are experienced with AppStore/TestFlight release process. If you aren't, please look into this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/133121/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html

Comment: I've distributed many apps, but my issue is that the extension is not included. Neither of those tutorials mention anything about extensions.

Comment: Then, I believe that you already have experience with provisioning profile and bundleID etc. You are supposed to create a separate provisioning profile to ship your app extension

Comment: Could you link to a source on that? The extension itself is an embedded binary within the app, I don't understand why it would be separate.

Comment: This is from personal experience in distributing app extensions. In the documentation, it is given that you are supposed to create a separate bundleID for watch extension app. So, I assumed that this also applies to other extensions. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW16

Answer (score 0):

you have to make new bundle id and provisioning profile for Notification extension too, when you will publish your app in test flight along with your main target distribution certificate you will find to choose certificate for your Notification Extension target also.

[Distribution Certificate for NSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbOwd.png)